# NSTextField Shows 'No Selection' Cocoa Bindings and Core Data in Swift in XCode 6.1

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, swift, cocoa-bindings

I can't get Cocoa Bindings and Core Data to work and I can't figure out where to find my answers.

I have an `Entity` Core Data Entity, with a `text` attribute.

[image: Core Data Entity]

***NB:*** This is the new *Storyboards* Document-based Xcode Template, so it has a View Controller in it and there's no link between the Window Controller and the View. Additionally, the Window Controller does not have a 'File's Owner'.

So, in order to have access to the Document's `managedObjectContext` I dragged in an `Object` and set its class to `Document`.

[image: Document Object]

I then bound my Array Controller to that Document Object's `managedObjectContext`. This all auto-completes so I'm assuming it's connecting right.

[image: Array Controller Binding]

***Edit:*** forgot to include this: The Array Controller is set to control the appropriate entity:

[image: Array Controller is in Entity Mode]

I have an NSTextField in my view, and I bound that to the Array Controller's `selection`'s `text` property — again, this autocompleted.

[image: Text Field Binding]

Here's my `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
class Entity: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var text: String

    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        self.text = "Hi"
    }

}
```

So it seems as though everything's hooked up, but when I launch the app, this is what I get:

[image: Result]

What am I doing wrong? Is the Cocoa Bindings part, the Core Data part, or something else that I'm not using correctly?

My interpretation is that while everything is bound correctly, the NSManagedObject is either not getting created or it's being created after the Array Controller can see it. I thought the point of this template was that it set everything up for you.

If you tell me to read Apple's Documentation, please point me to the right starting point because I have spent two days poring over the relevant Class References, Core Data and Document-based Application Guides, and Cocoa Bindings docs and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How are you creating the array? How are you selecting the entity to fill the text field? Normally an app would have a table view showing the entities where you could select one and have it fill the text field. By the way, I'm going to delete my answer since you updated your question with information on how you configured the array controller, making my answer irrelevant.

Comment: Mark, I haven't done anything beyond what I describe above. I thought the Array Controller would take care of populating an array dynamically based on the entity. In this example I would only have one Entity per document, so no UI to make a selection will be made available. Should I be using something other than an Array Controller for bindings then? Regardless, how do I manage the leap from Entity to Managed Object to whatever an Object/Array Controller needs to provide data to the view?

Comment: If you have only one entity, use an object controller instead of an array controller. You can do the same bindings you've done with the array controller with an object controller. I'm not sure how you would get the selection. You'll also need to write code to insert your entity into the managed object context. Currently you have no code to add entities to the managed object context. The code would be a method in your NSPersistentDocument subclass. Look at the function NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName().

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I had looked at that, will look again. Your answer does clarify something valuable for me—I thought the NSPersistentDocument would insert the Entity automatically.